# is bool datatype portable in c++?

Tags: c++

Can `bool` datatype be used in C++ and can portability still be ensured?

There are discussions about this partially in other posts, but does not specifically discuss portability.

I would like to know if I can use `bool` and be sure it will compile in most systems (say 99%), if not all systems.

Comment: Perhaps link to posts that suggest this wouldn't be possible? It's a built in type to C++

Comment: 99% is too conservative.

Comment: Yes, I got confused with C.. The question is answered too well.. Thank you all for the answers (and the downvotes).  I am inserting this comment before I lose my ability to comment :-).

Comment: And even C does not means much: C99 is different of C89 (and `bool` is mentioned in C99)

Comment: What is data type portability?

Comment: @arun Nice quip, upvote just for that.  You can always comment on your own posts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`bool` is a builtin type since the first C++ standard (C++98), so if you have a compiler that conforms to *any* C++ standard (and arguably, any compiler from the last 20 years) you should be set.

As for pre-standard C++, looking around it seems that, on PC compilers, it made its appearance around 1996-1997 (Visual C++ 5, Borland C++ 5); indeed, [GotW #26](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/026.htm) mentions that `bool` is "the only builtin datatype to be added to C++ since [Stroutroup's] Annotated C++ Reference Manual" (1990), so it's reasonable to deduce that it was born somewhere between 1990 and 1996. Reading around the web 1993 is thrown around quite often as "birth date" for `bool` in C++, but I couldn't find a single reliable reference for it.

Although you can still find obsolete pages (mostly from university courses) that explain how to workaround the absence of `bool` in old compilers, nowadays there are no compatibility issues using it, unless you are forced to use really ancient toolchains (I'm looking at you, university courses which recommend Turbo C++ in 2018).

Maybe you got confused with C, where `bool` appeared only in C99?

---

> Was `bool` available in pre-standard C++ (like Cfront)?

Looking at [the sources of Cfront 3.0.3](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/c_plus_plus/index.html#release_30) (1994, although the original 3.0 was released in 1991), `bool` is thrown around quite a bit indeed, especially in standard headers such as `basic_string.h`.

As for its definition, there is an insane mix of [`typedef char bool;`](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/c_plus_plus/cfront/release_3.0.3/source/incl-master/const-headers/basic_string.h/view) (but inside an `#ifdef CFRONT_COMPATIBLE_LUCENT`, so maybe it's just a compatibility definition? And WTF, the copyright date is 1996?), [`#define bool char`](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/c_plus_plus/cfront/release_3.0.3/source/incl-master/proto-headers/curses.sgi/view), [`enum bool { false, true };`](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/c_plus_plus/cfront/release_3.0.3/source/src/template.h/view), as well as a [`typedef int bool;`](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/c_plus_plus/cfront/release_3.0.3/source/incl-master/const-headers/std_bool.h/view) in a promisingly-named std_bool.h header (which however has copyright date 1996 as well!).

Looking at the lexer and the parser I couldn't find mentions of `bool`, although [the demangler](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/c_plus_plus/cfront/release_3.0.3/source/demangle/dem.c/view) cites it as a fundamental type, so there is some evidence that somebody thought it was (or, was going to be) a builtin.

Still, while its precise definition is a bit of a blur, as said above *something* named `bool` with `true` and `false` values *was* indeed available and used in the standard library, so, if you plan to compile your code with Cfront 3.0, `bool` is probably going to be the least of your concerns. :-)

Incidentally, this trip down ancient C++ brings some sadness as well: Cfront 3.0 [shipped with a C++ regex library](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/c_plus_plus/cfront/release_3.0.3/source/incl-master/const-headers/Regex.h/view), something that we had to wait for C++11 to get back again (and which remained segfault-level broken for quite some more years in libstdc++).

Comment: Was `bool` available in pre-standard C++ (like Cfront)?

Comment: Don't know about Cfront, but checking around it seems that it was available in Borland C++ from version 5.0 (1996) and in Visual C++ 5 (1997), so that's definitely pre-standard, but not by much. Lookin for this information was an interesting immersion in ancient web (which often coincides with obsolete University courses pages), where they recommend the workarounds to use if you are stuck with Borland C++ 4 (or - God forbid it - Turbo C++).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: ok, you got me curious and I looked up the sources of Cfront 3 - and `bool` was *somewhat* there; see the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I would like you to see the answer of @SoronelHaetir too.

Answer (score 8):

`bool` is a built-in type so it is **as portable as the C++ language itself**

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you are worried about storage portability (serialization) then bool is not a particularly portable type, the size is not tied down (indeed it is hardly ever the same size as 'char').

This despite the fact that bool has been in c++ as long as the language has been standardized.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.. I started using bool, then after seeing this I changed it to char.  I don't do serialization, but stack usage matters to me as I am also targeting systems that have just 2k of RAM. I am also aware that using char does not guarantee just one byte usage, as there are alignment issues.

Comment: Well, no fundamental type in C has its size or - FWIW - its byte representation tied down; if you care about exact size you should use the types from `stdint.h`.

Comment: @arunatsiara.cc: `char` does guarantee one byte usage - by C++ standard, it's the *definition* of byte, and the least possibly aligned type. OTOH, there are some exotic platforms where `char` is greater than 8 bit, but in those cases it's usually because the hardware cannot address smaller memory entities individually.

Comment: @Matteo Italia - do you mean to say if I use char or int8_t from stdint.h, it will occupy just one byte on stack (for c++)?

Comment: *indeed it is hardly ever the same size as 'char'* can you name a compiler/platform where it isn't? It's true that it is not required to be 1 (and indeed, the standard explicitly specifies it explicitly at C++11, [expr.sizeof], note 75), but on any compiler/platform I can think of (and that I tried on gcc.godbolt) `sizeof(bool)==1`.

Comment: @arunatsiara.cc: in line of principle, yes, although of course if you have different data types on the same stack frame the compiler must be smart enough to reorder them to keep the wasted space for alignment of bigger types at minimum. For structures it's more complicated as generally the ABI mandates that the order of fields must be kept as written, so you are responsible for it.

Answer (score -4):

**[C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B) does not mean much** (it is more a family of related languages, than a single one). You need to target a *specific* C++ standard. Consider at least C++11 (but don't bother about older standards, which probably mentioned `bool` also), and if possible C++14.

Then  `bool` is part of C++11 (and also of later standards like C++14 or C++17). Check by reading [n3337](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n3337.pdf). It was also part of C++98 but you should not care.

(Notice that C++ has changed a lot since C++11 included, this is why I don't recommend using older standards like C++98; and portability matters only when referring to a particular standard; it usually does not make sense to write code portable to all of C++98, C++11, C++17, C++20)

If you want to code for an obsolete standard like C++98 something which could compile with a later standard-conforming compiler (e.g. some C++17 compatible one) you should ask a different question. `bool` is then not an issue, but you have many other (more important) ones.

The question of what is the C++ standard supported on most platforms is a very different one. If you can afford using *recent* compilers (e.g. if you can install recent versions of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/)) I would bet on C++11.

You'll certainly be able to find, perhaps in some museum, an obsolete computer which has a C++98 compiler but not a C++11 one. You could even find computers without C++ compilers (or even without any compilers).

Certainly, an old Sun3/60 from 1987 in a museum accepts a C++ dialect (perhaps some [Cfront](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cfront)) very different of the several [dialects of C++](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html) accepted by GCC 8 on my Linux desktop.

**What you want to code against is a standard** (such as C++11,  which, like C++98, C++14, C++17 also mentions `bool`). **This ensures portability to other implementations of the *same* standard**. Of course C++98, C++11, C++14, C++17 all mention `bool`; but if you want to code against *several* C++ standards (and this could be difficult) you need a lot of care (probably using some preprocessor conditionals to provide different code for different C++ standards when that is needed).

Comment: `bool` has been in C++ since the beginning. I think this is why people are downvoting

Comment: You're implying `bool` is a new feature in C++11 when it's actually older than the first C++ standard.

Comment: "*You should require C++14*" is not a good response to "*I am concerned about portability*".

Comment: You are not answering the question. The question is about portability, and your answer is about compatibility. You are mixing up two concepts, and your descriptions are disjoint from reality.